# Magento Order report

Tags: magento-1.9, orders, collection, email, reports

I got mail every week order report below is the code

```
<?php
include 'app/Mage.php';
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
Mage::app();
    $ordershippeddays = 7; // number of days you want
    $fromDate = gmdate("Y-m-d H:i:s", gmmktime(0, 0, 0, gmdate("m"), gmdate("d") - $ordershippeddays, gmdate("Y")));
    $toDate = gmdate("Y-m-d H:i:s", gmmktime(23, 59, 59, gmdate("m"), gmdate("d"), gmdate("Y")));

     $ordercollection = Mage::getResourceModel('sales/order_item_collection')
    ->addAttributeToSelect('order_id')
    ->addAttributeToSelect('created_at')
    ->addAttributeToFilter('created_at', array('from' => $fromDate, 'to' => $toDate))
    ->load();
    $orderCount = count($ordercollection);
    Mage::log($orderCount,null,'custom.log');
    $tableHeaderHtml = '<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="650" style="border:1px solid #eaeaea"><thead><tr>';
    $tableHeaderHtml .= '<th align="center" bgcolor="#EAEAEA" style="font-size:13px;padding:3px 9px;">Order Id</th><th align="center" bgcolor="#EAEAEA" style="font-size:13px;padding:3px 9px;">Name</th>';
    $tableHeaderHtml .= '<th align="center" bgcolor="#EAEAEA" style="font-size:13px;padding:3px 9px;">Email</th><th align="center" bgcolor="#EAEAEA" style="font-size:13px;padding:3px 9px;">Payment Method</th>';
    $tableHeaderHtml .= '<th align="center" bgcolor="#EAEAEA" style="font-size:13px;padding:3px 9px;">Order Status</th><th align="center" bgcolor="#EAEAEA" style="font-size:13px;padding:3px 9px;">Product Name</th>';
    $tableHeaderHtml .= '<th align="center" bgcolor="#EAEAEA" style="font-size:13px;padding:3px 9px;">Billing Address</th><th align="center" bgcolor="#EAEAEA" style="font-size:13px;padding:3px 9px;">Shipping Address</th>';
    $tableHeaderHtml .= '</tr></thead><tbody bgcolor="#F6F6F6">';
    $processedTemplate .="";
    foreach ($ordercollection as $orderkey => $ordervalue) {
    $eid = $ordervalue->getOrderId();   
    $order = Mage::getModel("sales/order")->load($eid);
    Mage::log("Testing success...........");
    $orderInfo = $order->getIncrementId().','.$order->getPayment()->getMethodInstance()->getTitle().','.$order->getStatusLabel().','.number_format ($order->getGrandTotal(), 2, '.' , $thousands_sep = '');
    $userDetails = $order->getCustomerName().','.$order->getCustomerEmail();            
    $billingAddress = $order->getBillingAddress();
    $shipping_address = $order->getShippingAddress();
    Mage::log($billingAddressFull = $billingAddress->getStreetFull().','.$billingAddress->getRegion().','.$billingAddress->getPostcode().','.$billingAddress->getCountry().', Mob: '.$billingAddress->getTelephone());
    Mage::log($shipping_addressFull = $shipping_address->getStreetFull().','.$shipping_address->getRegion().','.$shipping_address->getPostcode().','.$shipping_address->getCountry().', Mob: '.$shipping_address->getTelephone());

    foreach ($order->getAllVisibleItems() as $item) {
        $productDetails = $item->getName().','.$item->getSku().', Qty: '.(int)$item->getQtyOrdered();
        $productName = $item->getName();

    $tableContentHtml = '<tr>';
    $tableContentHtml .= '<td align="left" valign="top" style="font-size:11px;padding:3px 9px;border-bottom:1px dotted #cccccc;">' . $order->getIncrementId() . '</td><td align="center" valign="top" style="font-size:11px;padding:3px 9px;border-bottom:1px dotted #cccccc;">' . $order->getCustomerName() . '</td>';
    $tableContentHtml .= '<td align="left" valign="top" style="font-size:11px;padding:3px 9px;border-bottom:1px dotted #cccccc;">' . $order->getCustomerEmail() . '</td><td align="center" valign="top" style="font-size:11px;padding:3px 9px;border-bottom:1px dotted #cccccc;">' . $order->getPayment()->getMethodInstance()->getTitle() . '</td>';
    $tableContentHtml .= '<td align="left" valign="top" style="font-size:11px;padding:3px 9px;border-bottom:1px dotted #cccccc;">' . $order->getStatusLabel() . '</td><td align="center" valign="top" style="font-size:11px;padding:3px 9px;border-bottom:1px dotted #cccccc;">' . $productName . '</td>';
    $tableContentHtml .= '<td align="left" valign="top" style="font-size:11px;padding:3px 9px;border-bottom:1px dotted #cccccc;">' . $billingAddressFull . '</td><td align="center" valign="top" style="font-size:11px;padding:3px 9px;border-bottom:1px dotted #cccccc;">' . $shipping_addressFull . '</td>';
    $tableContentHtml .= '<tr>'; 
    Mage::log($productName,null,'custom.log');
    $template_id = 'order_update_email';
      $email_to = 'my@gmail.com';
      $customer_name   = "Test";
      $email_template  = Mage::getModel('core/email_template')->loadDefault($template_id);
      $email_template_variables = array(
          'custom_variable' => $fromDate,
          'custom_variable1' => $toDate,
          'custom_variable3' =>$orderCount,
          'custom_variable4'=>$orderInfo,
          'custom_variable5'=>$tableHeaderHtml,
          'custom_variable6'=>$tableContentHtml
      );


      $processedTemplate .= $email_template->getProcessedTemplate($email_template_variables);
      // echo $processedTemplate;
      // exit();
     // $sender_name = 'Admin';
     // $sender_email = Mage::getStoreConfig('trans_email/ident_general/email');
     // $email_template->setSenderName($sender_name);
     // $email_template->setSenderEmail($sender_email); 
    //  $email_template->send($email_to, $customer_name, $email_template_variables);


    }
    }

    $mail = Mage::getModel('core/email');
    $mail->setToName('My Name');
    $mail->setToEmail('mymail@gmail');
    $mail->setBody($processedTemplate);
    $mail->setSubject('Test');
    $mail->setFromEmail('mymail@gmail');
    $mail->setFromName("Msg to Show on Subject");
    $mail->setType('html');// YOu can use Html or text as Mail format
    $mail->send();

?>
```

I added this in my root file then i will run. I din't get any mail.

Also i add and check this

```
$processedTemplate .= $email_template->getProcessedTemplate($email_template_variables);
           echo $processedTemplate;
           exit();
```

I got only one order information in that mail. Also that order have 2 products but it showing only one.

How i fix this issue?

**email template**

```
<!--@subject Order Update Email {{var custom_variable}} - {{var custom_variable1}}! @-->
<!--@vars
{"store url=\"\"":"Store Url",
"var logo_url":"Email Logo Image Url",
"htmlescape var=$customer.name":"Customer Name",
"store url=\"customer/account/\"":"Customer Account Url",
"var customer.email":"Customer Email",
"htmlescape var=$customer.password":"Customer Password"}
@-->

<!--@styles
body,td { color:#2f2f2f; font:11px/1.35em Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; }
@-->

<body style="background:#F6F6F6; font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:12px; margin:0; padding:0;">
<div style="background:#F6F6F6; font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:12px; margin:0; padding:0;">
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" height="100%" width="100%">
        <tr>
            <td align="center" valign="top" style="padding:20px 0 20px 0">
                <!-- [ header starts here] -->
                <table bgcolor="FFFFFF" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="10" border="0" width="650" style="border:1px solid #E0E0E0;">
                    <tr>
                        <td valign="top">
                            <a href="{{store url=""}}"><img src="{{var logo_url}}" alt="{{var logo_alt}}" style="margin-bottom:10px;" border="0"/></a>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                <!-- [ middle starts here] -->
                    <tr>
                        <td valign="top">
                            <h1 style="font-size:22px; font-weight:normal; line-height:22px; margin:0 0 11px 0;">Dear Admin,</h1>
                            <p style="font-size:12px; line-height:16px; margin:0 0 16px 0;">Please Check Below Order report on {{var custom_variable}} - {{var custom_variable1}}</p>
                            <p style="font-size:12px; line-height:16px; margin:0 0 16px 0;">Total Number of Order :{{var custom_variable3}}</p>
                            {{var custom_variable5}}{{var custom_variable6}}
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td bgcolor="#EAEAEA" align="center" style="background:#EAEAEA; text-align:center;"><center><p style="font-size:12px; margin:0;">Thank you again, <strong>{{var store.getFrontendName()}}</strong></p></center></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: you want to send email separately for every order?

Comment: Only one mail that mail conatain all report of that 7 days

Comment: then don't use the template for that create HTML  for every order and send email it is simple.

Comment: Sorry i am not getting

Comment: i added the solution below use that.

Comment: can you email template here too so i can test it?

Comment: Plz check my updated question

Comment: updated the answer after some changes i got required result

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$ordershippeddays = 4257; // number of days you want
    $fromDate = gmdate("Y-m-d H:i:s", gmmktime(0, 0, 0, gmdate("m"), gmdate("d") - $ordershippeddays, gmdate("Y")));
    $toDate = gmdate("Y-m-d H:i:s", gmmktime(23, 59, 59, gmdate("m"), gmdate("d"), gmdate("Y")));

     $ordercollection = Mage::getResourceModel('sales/order_item_collection')
    ->addAttributeToSelect('order_id')
    ->addAttributeToSelect('created_at')
    ->addAttributeToFilter('created_at', array('from' => $fromDate, 'to' => $toDate))->setPageSize(7)
    ->load();
$processedTemplate="";
 $tableHeaderHtml = '<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="650" style="border:1px solid #eaeaea"><thead><tr>';
    $tableHeaderHtml .= '<th align="center" bgcolor="#EAEAEA" style="font-size:13px;padding:3px 9px;">Order Id</th><th align="center" bgcolor="#EAEAEA" style="font-size:13px;padding:3px 9px;">Name</th>';
    $tableHeaderHtml .= '<th align="center" bgcolor="#EAEAEA" style="font-size:13px;padding:3px 9px;">Email</th><th align="center" bgcolor="#EAEAEA" style="font-size:13px;padding:3px 9px;">Payment Method</th>';
    $tableHeaderHtml .= '<th align="center" bgcolor="#EAEAEA" style="font-size:13px;padding:3px 9px;">Order Status</th><th align="center" bgcolor="#EAEAEA" style="font-size:13px;padding:3px 9px;">Product Name</th>';
    $tableHeaderHtml .= '<th align="center" bgcolor="#EAEAEA" style="font-size:13px;padding:3px 9px;">Billing Address</th><th align="center" bgcolor="#EAEAEA" style="font-size:13px;padding:3px 9px;">Shipping Address</th>';
    $tableHeaderHtml .= '</tr></thead><tbody bgcolor="#F6F6F6">';
    $tableContentHtml ="";
foreach ($ordercollection as  $ordervalue) {
           echo  $eid = $ordervalue->getOrderId(); 

            $order = Mage::getModel("sales/order")->load($eid);
            Mage::log("Testing success...........");
            $orderInfo = $order->getIncrementId().',,'.$order->getStatusLabel().','.number_format ($order->getGrandTotal(), 2, '.' , $thousands_sep = '');
            $userDetails = $order->getCustomerName().','.$order->getCustomerEmail();            
            $billingAddress = $order->getBillingAddress();
            $shipping_address = $order->getShippingAddress();
     //       Mage::log($billingAddressFull = $billingAddress->getStreetFull().','.$billingAddress->getRegion().','.$billingAddress->getPostcode().','.$billingAddress->getCountry().', Mob: '.$billingAddress->getTelephone());
       //     Mage::log($shipping_addressFull = $shipping_address->getStreetFull().','.$shipping_address->getRegion().','.$shipping_address->getPostcode().','.$shipping_address->getCountry().', Mob: '.$shipping_address->getTelephone());

        foreach ($order->getAllVisibleItems() as $item) {
             $productDetails = $item->getName().','.$item->getSku().', Qty: '.(int)$item->getQtyOrdered();
            $productName = $item->getName();

        $tableContentHtml .= '<tr>';
        $tableContentHtml .= '<td align="left" valign="top" style="font-size:11px;padding:3px 9px;border-bottom:1px dotted #cccccc;">' . $order->getIncrementId() . '</td><td align="center" valign="top" style="font-size:11px;padding:3px 9px;border-bottom:1px dotted #cccccc;">' . $order->getCustomerName() . '</td>';
        $tableContentHtml .= '<td align="left" valign="top" style="font-size:11px;padding:3px 9px;border-bottom:1px dotted #cccccc;">' . $order->getCustomerEmail() . '</td><td align="center" valign="top" style="font-size:11px;padding:3px 9px;border-bottom:1px dotted #cccccc;">' . $order->getPayment()->getMethodInstance()->getTitle() . '</td>';
        $tableContentHtml .= '<td align="left" valign="top" style="font-size:11px;padding:3px 9px;border-bottom:1px dotted #cccccc;">' . $order->getStatusLabel() . '</td><td align="center" valign="top" style="font-size:11px;padding:3px 9px;border-bottom:1px dotted #cccccc;">' . $productName . '</td>';
        $tableContentHtml .= '<td align="left" valign="top" style="font-size:11px;padding:3px 9px;border-bottom:1px dotted #cccccc;">' . $billingAddressFull . '</td><td align="center" valign="top" style="font-size:11px;padding:3px 9px;border-bottom:1px dotted #cccccc;">' . $shipping_addressFull . '</td>';
        $tableContentHtml .= '</tr>'; 
       // Mage::log($productName,null,'custom.log');

         // $sender_name = 'Admin';
         // $sender_email = Mage::getStoreConfig('trans_email/ident_general/email');
         // $email_template->setSenderName($sender_name);
         // $email_template->setSenderEmail($sender_email); 
        //  $email_template->send($email_to, $customer_name, $email_template_variables);


        }

         // print_r($email_template_variables);



        }
$template_id = 'order_update_email';
          $email_to = 'my@gmail.com';
          $customer_name   = "Test";
          $email_template  = Mage::getModel('core/email_template')->loadDefault($template_id);
          $store = Mage::app()->getStore();
                $iDefaultStoreId = Mage::app()
                ->getWebsite()
                ->getDefaultGroup()
                ->getDefaultStoreId();
                $email_template->setDesignConfig(array('area' => 'frontend', 'store' => $iDefaultStoreId));
         // print_r($email_template);
          $custom_variable = "Nmae";
          $custom_variable1 = 'my@gmail.com';
          $custom_variable2 = '1234567890';
          $email_template_variables = array(
              'custom_variable' => $fromDate,
              'custom_variable1' => $toDate,
              'custom_variable3' =>$orderCount,
              'custom_variable4'=>$orderInfo,
              'custom_variable5'=>$tableHeaderHtml,
              'custom_variable6'=>$tableContentHtml

          );
        $processedTemplate = $email_template->getProcessedTemplate($email_template_variables); 
        echo $processedTemplate;

        $mail = Mage::getModel('core/email');
$mail->setToName('Your Name');
$mail->setToEmail('Youe Email');
$mail->setBody($processedTemplate);
$mail->setSubject('Mail Subject');
$mail->setFromEmail('Sender Mail Id');
$mail->setFromName("Msg to Show on Subject");
$mail->setType('html');// YOu can use Html or text as Mail format
$mail->send();
```

output

[image]

also some changes then the result will

```
$ordershippeddays = 4257; // number of days you want
    $fromDate = gmdate("Y-m-d H:i:s", gmmktime(0, 0, 0, gmdate("m"), gmdate("d") - $ordershippeddays, gmdate("Y")));
    $toDate = gmdate("Y-m-d H:i:s", gmmktime(23, 59, 59, gmdate("m"), gmdate("d"), gmdate("Y")));

     $ordercollection = Mage::getResourceModel('sales/order_item_collection')
    ->addAttributeToSelect('order_id')
    ->addAttributeToSelect('created_at')
    ->addAttributeToFilter('created_at', array('from' => $fromDate, 'to' => $toDate))->setPageSize(7);
$processedTemplate="";
 $tableHeaderHtml = '<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="650" style="border:1px solid #eaeaea"><thead><tr>';
    $tableHeaderHtml .= '<th align="center" bgcolor="#EAEAEA" style="font-size:13px;padding:3px 9px;">Order Id</th><th align="center" bgcolor="#EAEAEA" style="font-size:13px;padding:3px 9px;">Name</th>';
    $tableHeaderHtml .= '<th align="center" bgcolor="#EAEAEA" style="font-size:13px;padding:3px 9px;">Email</th><th align="center" bgcolor="#EAEAEA" style="font-size:13px;padding:3px 9px;">Payment Method</th>';
    $tableHeaderHtml .= '<th align="center" bgcolor="#EAEAEA" style="font-size:13px;padding:3px 9px;">Order Status</th><th align="center" bgcolor="#EAEAEA" style="font-size:13px;padding:3px 9px;">Product Name</th>';
    $tableHeaderHtml .= '<th align="center" bgcolor="#EAEAEA" style="font-size:13px;padding:3px 9px;">Billing Address</th><th align="center" bgcolor="#EAEAEA" style="font-size:13px;padding:3px 9px;">Shipping Address</th>';
    $tableHeaderHtml .= '</tr></thead><tbody bgcolor="#F6F6F6">';
    $arraything=[];
foreach ($ordercollection as  $ordervalue) {
            $eid = $ordervalue->getOrderId(); 
            $order = Mage::getModel("sales/order")->load($eid);
            Mage::log("Testing success...........");
            $orderInfo = $order->getIncrementId().',,'.$order->getStatusLabel().','.number_format ($order->getGrandTotal(), 2, '.' , $thousands_sep = '');
            $userDetails = $order->getCustomerName().','.$order->getCustomerEmail();            
            $billingAddress = $order->getBillingAddress();
            $shipping_address = $order->getShippingAddress();
     //       Mage::log($billingAddressFull = $billingAddress->getStreetFull().','.$billingAddress->getRegion().','.$billingAddress->getPostcode().','.$billingAddress->getCountry().', Mob: '.$billingAddress->getTelephone());
       //     Mage::log($shipping_addressFull = $shipping_address->getStreetFull().','.$shipping_address->getRegion().','.$shipping_address->getPostcode().','.$shipping_address->getCountry().', Mob: '.$shipping_address->getTelephone());
        $tableContentHtml = '<tr>';
        $tableContentHtml .= '<td align="left" valign="top" style="font-size:11px;padding:3px 9px;border-bottom:1px dotted #cccccc;">' . $order->getIncrementId() . '</td><td align="center" valign="top" style="font-size:11px;padding:3px 9px;border-bottom:1px dotted #cccccc;">' . $order->getCustomerName() . '</td>';
        $tableContentHtml .= '<td align="left" valign="top" style="font-size:11px;padding:3px 9px;border-bottom:1px dotted #cccccc;">' . $order->getCustomerEmail() . '</td><td align="center" valign="top" style="font-size:11px;padding:3px 9px;border-bottom:1px dotted #cccccc;">' . $order->getPayment()->getMethodInstance()->getTitle() . '</td>';
        $tableContentHtml .= '<td align="left" valign="top" style="font-size:11px;padding:3px 9px;border-bottom:1px dotted #cccccc;">' . $order->getStatusLabel() . '</td><td align="center" valign="top" style="font-size:11px;padding:3px 9px;border-bottom:1px dotted #cccccc;">';
        foreach ($order->getAllVisibleItems() as $item) {
             $productDetails = $item->getName().','.$item->getSku().', Qty: '.(int)$item->getQtyOrdered();
            $productName = $item->getName();


         $tableContentHtml .= $productName . '<br />';
       // Mage::log($productName,null,'custom.log');

         // $sender_name = 'Admin';
         // $sender_email = Mage::getStoreConfig('trans_email/ident_general/email');
         // $email_template->setSenderName($sender_name);
         // $email_template->setSenderEmail($sender_email); 
        //  $email_template->send($email_to, $customer_name, $email_template_variables);


        }
        $tableContentHtml .='</td>';
        $tableContentHtml .= '<td align="left" valign="top" style="font-size:11px;padding:3px 9px;border-bottom:1px dotted #cccccc;">' . $billingAddressFull . '</td><td align="center" valign="top" style="font-size:11px;padding:3px 9px;border-bottom:1px dotted #cccccc;">' . $shipping_addressFull . '</td>';
        $tableContentHtml .= '</tr>'; 
        $arraything[]=$tableContentHtml;

         // print_r($email_template_variables);



        }


$template_id = 'order_update_email';
          $email_to = 'my@gmail.com';
          $customer_name   = "Test";
          $email_template  = Mage::getModel('core/email_template')->loadDefault($template_id);
          $store = Mage::app()->getStore();
                $iDefaultStoreId = Mage::app()
                ->getWebsite()
                ->getDefaultGroup()
                ->getDefaultStoreId();
                $email_template->setDesignConfig(array('area' => 'frontend', 'store' => $iDefaultStoreId));
         // print_r($email_template);
          $custom_variable = "Nmae";
          $custom_variable1 = 'my@gmail.com';
          $custom_variable2 = '1234567890';
          $email_template_variables = array(
              'custom_variable' => $fromDate,
              'custom_variable1' => $toDate,
              'custom_variable3' =>$orderCount,
              'custom_variable4'=>$orderInfo,
              'custom_variable5'=>$tableHeaderHtml,
              'custom_variable6'=>implode(' ', $arraything)

          );
        $processedTemplate = $email_template->getProcessedTemplate($email_template_variables); 
        echo $processedTemplate;

        $mail = Mage::getModel('core/email');
$mail->setToName('Your Name');
$mail->setToEmail('Youe Email');
$mail->setBody($processedTemplate);
$mail->setSubject('Mail Subject');
$mail->setFromEmail('Sender Mail Id');
$mail->setFromName("Msg to Show on Subject");
$mail->setType('html');
```

output

[image]

Comment: I didn't get any mail after adding this

Comment: i got a mail but last product only not all

Comment: @Kothari  `echo $processedTemplate; exit;` after loop and check you get all order output or not?

Comment: No i got only one

Comment: please check my update question

Comment: @Kothari   also use replace `$email_template  = Mage::getModel('core/email_template')->loadDefault($template_id);` with `$email_template  = Mage::getModel('core/email_template')->load($template_id);`

Comment: i din;t get any mail same problem

Comment: can you please update full code

Comment: in same table i can't able to get all infomation

Comment: @Kothari updated the code that i tested. make sure your template is showing and change things as your requirement

Comment: Still i am get different different table for each product

Comment: @Kothari mean you get all the product. did you replace code with mine? i am getting this like output

Comment: Ya the problem is i need only one table in that all information will come insted of disply different different table for each order

Comment: @Kothari that is not you mention before dear then we can do it simple way. le me update the code.

Comment: Sorry i edited my qustion that time i skip it

Comment: @Kothari update hope you get what you want.

Comment: Some order's repeted your output screen also same

Comment: @Kothari because for every  product you are showing the order id too now it's your hand

Comment: check your order id 52 it have 2 product so it shows only two time but it shows 4 time

Comment: @Kothari ok i will check and update

Comment: @Kothari these are repeating they are order their so it is showing correct result 1000051 and 100051-1 these are two order in admin

Comment: Awaard show after 3 hrs i will add it after 3hrs award thanks for help

Comment: @Kothari  i am glad i can help :)

Comment: I placed one order it shows two time

Comment: @Kothari check the query and use **distinct** for that so it will not repeated. i cannot check it now i am not on my pc.

Comment: Sorry i am not getting

Comment: if order has 2 product then it come 2 time

Comment: @Kothari yes in that case

Comment: Ya what will do in that cse

Comment: @Kothari use group by order_id is good option

Comment: You mean change the collection

Comment: yes that is exactly what i mean

Answer (score 1):

Problem that you are getting one product is related to your `tr` structure

find

```
    $tableContentHtml = '<tr>';
    $tableContentHtml .= '<td align="left" valign="top" style="font-size:11px;padding:3px 9px;border-bottom:1px dotted #cccccc;">' . $order->getIncrementId() . '</td><td align="center" valign="top" style="font-size:11px;padding:3px 9px;border-bottom:1px dotted #cccccc;">' . $order->getCustomerName() . '</td>';
    $tableContentHtml .= '<td align="left" valign="top" style="font-size:11px;padding:3px 9px;border-bottom:1px dotted #cccccc;">' . $order->getCustomerEmail() . '</td><td align="center" valign="top" style="font-size:11px;padding:3px 9px;border-bottom:1px dotted #cccccc;">' . $order->getPayment()->getMethodInstance()->getTitle() . '</td>';
    $tableContentHtml .= '<td align="left" valign="top" style="font-size:11px;padding:3px 9px;border-bottom:1px dotted #cccccc;">' . $order->getStatusLabel() . '</td><td align="center" valign="top" style="font-size:11px;padding:3px 9px;border-bottom:1px dotted #cccccc;">' . $productName . '</td>';
    $tableContentHtml .= '<td align="left" valign="top" style="font-size:11px;padding:3px 9px;border-bottom:1px dotted #cccccc;">' . $billingAddressFull . '</td><td align="center" valign="top" style="font-size:11px;padding:3px 9px;border-bottom:1px dotted #cccccc;">' . $shipping_addressFull . '</td>';
    $tableContentHtml .= '<tr>';
```

replace

```
    $tableContentHtml .= '<tr>';
    $tableContentHtml .= '<td align="left" valign="top" style="font-size:11px;padding:3px 9px;border-bottom:1px dotted #cccccc;">' . $order->getIncrementId() . '</td><td align="center" valign="top" style="font-size:11px;padding:3px 9px;border-bottom:1px dotted #cccccc;">' . $order->getCustomerName() . '</td>';
    $tableContentHtml .= '<td align="left" valign="top" style="font-size:11px;padding:3px 9px;border-bottom:1px dotted #cccccc;">' . $order->getCustomerEmail() . '</td><td align="center" valign="top" style="font-size:11px;padding:3px 9px;border-bottom:1px dotted #cccccc;">' . $order->getPayment()->getMethodInstance()->getTitle() . '</td>';
    $tableContentHtml .= '<td align="left" valign="top" style="font-size:11px;padding:3px 9px;border-bottom:1px dotted #cccccc;">' . $order->getStatusLabel() . '</td><td align="center" valign="top" style="font-size:11px;padding:3px 9px;border-bottom:1px dotted #cccccc;">' . $productName . '</td>';
    $tableContentHtml .= '<td align="left" valign="top" style="font-size:11px;padding:3px 9px;border-bottom:1px dotted #cccccc;">' . $billingAddressFull . '</td><td align="center" valign="top" style="font-size:11px;padding:3px 9px;border-bottom:1px dotted #cccccc;">' . $shipping_addressFull . '</td>';
    $tableContentHtml .= '</tr>';
```

**Updated code**

```
<?php
include 'app/Mage.php';
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
Mage::app();
$ordershippeddays = 7; // number of days you want
$fromDate = gmdate("Y-m-d H:i:s", gmmktime(0, 0, 0, gmdate("m"), gmdate("d") - $ordershippeddays, gmdate("Y")));
$toDate = gmdate("Y-m-d H:i:s", gmmktime(23, 59, 59, gmdate("m"), gmdate("d"), gmdate("Y")));

$ordercollection = Mage::getResourceModel('sales/order_item_collection')
        ->addAttributeToSelect('order_id')
        ->addAttributeToSelect('created_at')
        ->addAttributeToFilter('created_at', array('from' => $fromDate, 'to' => $toDate))
        ->load();
$orderCount = count($ordercollection);
Mage::log($orderCount, null, 'custom.log');
$tableHeaderHtml = '<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="650" style="border:1px solid #eaeaea"><thead><tr>';
$tableHeaderHtml .= '<th align="center" bgcolor="#EAEAEA" style="font-size:13px;padding:3px 9px;">Order Id</th><th align="center" bgcolor="#EAEAEA" style="font-size:13px;padding:3px 9px;">Name</th>';
$tableHeaderHtml .= '<th align="center" bgcolor="#EAEAEA" style="font-size:13px;padding:3px 9px;">Email</th><th align="center" bgcolor="#EAEAEA" style="font-size:13px;padding:3px 9px;">Payment Method</th>';
$tableHeaderHtml .= '<th align="center" bgcolor="#EAEAEA" style="font-size:13px;padding:3px 9px;">Order Status</th><th align="center" bgcolor="#EAEAEA" style="font-size:13px;padding:3px 9px;">Product Name</th>';
$tableHeaderHtml .= '<th align="center" bgcolor="#EAEAEA" style="font-size:13px;padding:3px 9px;">Billing Address</th><th align="center" bgcolor="#EAEAEA" style="font-size:13px;padding:3px 9px;">Shipping Address</th>';
$tableHeaderHtml .= '</tr></thead><tbody bgcolor="#F6F6F6">';
$processedTemplate .="";
foreach ($ordercollection as $orderkey => $ordervalue) {
    $eid = $ordervalue->getOrderId();
    $order = Mage::getModel("sales/order")->load($eid);
    Mage::log("Testing success...........");
    $orderInfo = $order->getIncrementId() . ',' . $order->getPayment()->getMethodInstance()->getTitle() . ',' . $order->getStatusLabel() . ',' . number_format($order->getGrandTotal(), 2, '.', $thousands_sep = '');
    $userDetails = $order->getCustomerName() . ',' . $order->getCustomerEmail();
    $billingAddress = $order->getBillingAddress();
    $shipping_address = $order->getShippingAddress();
    Mage::log($billingAddressFull = $billingAddress->getStreetFull() . ',' . $billingAddress->getRegion() . ',' . $billingAddress->getPostcode() . ',' . $billingAddress->getCountry() . ', Mob: ' . $billingAddress->getTelephone());
    Mage::log($shipping_addressFull = $shipping_address->getStreetFull() . ',' . $shipping_address->getRegion() . ',' . $shipping_address->getPostcode() . ',' . $shipping_address->getCountry() . ', Mob: ' . $shipping_address->getTelephone());

    foreach ($order->getAllVisibleItems() as $item) {
        $productDetails = $item->getName() . ',' . $item->getSku() . ', Qty: ' . (int) $item->getQtyOrdered();
        $productName = $item->getName();

        $tableContentHtml .= '<tr>';
        $tableContentHtml .= '<td align="left" valign="top" style="font-size:11px;padding:3px 9px;border-bottom:1px dotted #cccccc;">' . $order->getIncrementId() . '</td><td align="center" valign="top" style="font-size:11px;padding:3px 9px;border-bottom:1px dotted #cccccc;">' . $order->getCustomerName() . '</td>';
        $tableContentHtml .= '<td align="left" valign="top" style="font-size:11px;padding:3px 9px;border-bottom:1px dotted #cccccc;">' . $order->getCustomerEmail() . '</td><td align="center" valign="top" style="font-size:11px;padding:3px 9px;border-bottom:1px dotted #cccccc;">' . $order->getPayment()->getMethodInstance()->getTitle() . '</td>';
        $tableContentHtml .= '<td align="left" valign="top" style="font-size:11px;padding:3px 9px;border-bottom:1px dotted #cccccc;">' . $order->getStatusLabel() . '</td><td align="center" valign="top" style="font-size:11px;padding:3px 9px;border-bottom:1px dotted #cccccc;">' . $productName . '</td>';
        $tableContentHtml .= '<td align="left" valign="top" style="font-size:11px;padding:3px 9px;border-bottom:1px dotted #cccccc;">' . $billingAddressFull . '</td><td align="center" valign="top" style="font-size:11px;padding:3px 9px;border-bottom:1px dotted #cccccc;">' . $shipping_addressFull . '</td>';
        $tableContentHtml .= '</tr>';
        Mage::log($productName, null, 'custom.log');

        // echo $processedTemplate;
        // exit();
        // $sender_name = 'Admin';
        // $sender_email = Mage::getStoreConfig('trans_email/ident_general/email');
        // $email_template->setSenderName($sender_name);
        // $email_template->setSenderEmail($sender_email); 
        //  $email_template->send($email_to, $customer_name, $email_template_variables);
    }

    $template_id = 'order_update_email';
    $email_to = 'my@gmail.com';
    $customer_name = "Test";
    $email_template = Mage::getModel('core/email_template')->loadDefault($template_id);
    $email_template_variables = array(
        'custom_variable' => $fromDate,
        'custom_variable1' => $toDate,
        'custom_variable3' => $orderCount,
        'custom_variable4' => $orderInfo,
        'custom_variable5' => $tableHeaderHtml,
        'custom_variable6' => $tableContentHtml
    );


    $processedTemplate .= $email_template->getProcessedTemplate($email_template_variables);


}

$mail = Mage::getModel('core/email');
$mail->setToName('My Name');
$mail->setToEmail('mymail@gmail');
$mail->setBody($processedTemplate);
$mail->setSubject('Test');
$mail->setFromEmail('mymail@gmail');
$mail->setFromName("Msg to Show on Subject");
$mail->setType('html'); // YOu can use Html or text as Mail format
$mail->send();
?>
```

Comment: Also, you're not closing your `<tr>` tag, you're opening a new one. Check the line after adding all `<td>` tags.

Comment: Still same i got only one info also no mail

Comment: @Kothari check updated code section

Comment: No maill ..............

Comment: @Kothari now all product display ??

Comment: How i check??????

Comment: @Kothari then How you check before ??

Comment: same way i tried but not working so that i am asking

Comment: i add this echo $processedTemplate;
 exit(); but it not exit